# Create stored procedure error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I create a extremely basic stored procedure but oracle toad always shows "Warning: compiled but with compilation errors".

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_history (
   tab1_name IN VARCHAR2

   )
AS

BEGIN

END;
```

Comment: Check the error message with `show errors`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not handle the empty block; so you can simply add a NULL statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_history (
   tab1_name IN VARCHAR2
   )
AS    
BEGIN
    null;
END;
```